# How does one add a partial index checking for NULL to a JSON column on Postgres?

Tags: json, postgresql, indexing

I've got a `json` column called `data` on Postgres, and I'd like to add a partial index that applies only to rows where this column is `null` - I basically need to find all the rows where `data` is `null` so I can put some data into them.

Trying to add an index gives an error about missing operator classes, though, because we can't index `json` types with a `btree` index. But I'm not trying to index a specific property either, for me to use `data->>property`. How can I index just the rows which have a `json` null in them?

Edit: The `jsonb` suggestion would work, but I'm stuck on 9.3 for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `JsonB` field which can be indexed.

The main difference between the `json` and `jsonb` is efficiency. The `json` type is like a 'source code' (in text form), which must be parsed on each execution; while `jsonb` data is like a 'compiled form', which is a lot faster to process/read, but slightly slower during insert operations.

`jsonb` also supports indexing, which can be an advantage. Once it is indexed, you can just use it in a `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myjsonfield IS NULL;`  I believe this is what you are trying to achieve.

**UPDATE (Postgres 9.3)**

Since `jsonb` is not possible (for that version), a workaround would be indexing the "converted" column? eg:

```
CREATE TABLE myjsontable (
  idfield integer NOT NULL,
  myjsonfield json,
  CONSTRAINT myjsontable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (idfield)
);
-- Create an index of the myjsonfield converted to the text field.
CREATE INDEX ON myjsontable ((myjsonfield::text));

SELECT * FROM myjsontable WHERE myjsonfield::TEXT IS NULL;
```

This will work too, with very minimal performance impact as the underlying `json` datatype is also a `text` datatype.

[image]

Comment: Should have mentioned, I'm stuck on Postgres 9.3 :(

Comment: Updated the answer with a workaround for Postgres 9.3. Hope that helps.

p/s: For small (test) table, you can confirm that the index is being used by executing SET ENABLE_SEQSCAN = FALSE; (separately) before hitting the SHIFT+F7 on the SELECT statement.
Remember to set it back to TRUE after.